# Address of a structure variable (in C)

Tags: c, structure

When I declare a structure below

```
struct {
 int a;
 int b;
} x;
```

`&x` is the address of the structure, right? But as far as I'm concerned, a structure is a collection of data, so I don't really understand what specific address `&x` points to. When you have an array, let's say,

```
char a[] = "This is a test";
```

`*a` points to the first element of the array `a[]`, which is `a[0]`. What about the case above?

Comment: Try `printf( "%p  %p\n",  &x, &x.a );`... What is the result?

Comment: It points to that collection of data, appropriately typed (so that `.a` and `.b` can be applied to it after dereferencing (or equivalently `->a` and `->b`). Because of how structs are required not to have padding at the front, that address can also be casted to a pointer pointing to the first element.

Comment: `&x` points to some memory that represents `x`. The standard has some rules about what that representation looks like, namely representations of each field of the struct in order, with optional unnamed padding between fields and at the end.

Comment: @AndyPreston Perhaps you meant something like `(char*)&x + sizeof(x.a)`, although the results of that are somewhat misleading, because whereas here it's likely that the two pointers are the same, there's no guarantee of that because of padding.

Comment: @AndyPreston ```sizeof(x.a)``` is 4. And ```&x+sizeof(x.a)``` is exactly the same as ```(&x)[4]```. And probably not that's expected nor intended.

Comment: `&x` is also the address of the first member of the `struct` but in this case is the wrong type. The first member is always at the beginning of the `struct`.

Comment: @armagedescu, general questions about programming language semantics are on topic here.

Comment: @armagedescu: What makes you think a question about general knowledge might have to be removed? Stack Overflow is for all types of programming questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I used terms General Knowledge, to formulate it in a friendly manner. But this is general question about very basic knowledge. Just put ```&x``` in memory window in a debugger and see what is in memory, if have doubts about C manuals. It is deeply opinion based, at least.

Comment: A stucture is a type that allows differing types to be consider a single object. See [C18 Standard  - 6.7.2.1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf) Within the struct the types contained within it are members of the struct. The address for struct object is the address of it's first member -- that's why the address of `a` and `x` are one in the same. This only holds for the first member. The standard allows padding bytes to be inserted within the struct at any position **except** before the first member.

Comment: @armagedescu, if those are your issues with the question then they are not well conveyed by the description "addressing general knowledge info, and there is no technical technical issue to be solved".

Comment: @JohnBollinger as you probably noted already {a lot happened so far}, it is missing the OP part of research to show his own steps performed in the effort to understand the question and to tell what exactly he didn't understand, after the research was done. There, on stackoverflow, is often pointed the right way to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

> as far as I'm concerned, a structure is a collection of data, so I don't really understand what specific address `&x` points to.

This answer exists and has an identity of its own, yet also comprises within it the quotation above and the sentence you are reading now.  Similarly, your "collection of data" is an object in its own right, comprising all its members.  Each such object that exists in a program has a representation in memory, within which are the representations of its members.

The address of a structure object is the address of that representation.  For this purpose, it does not matter what form the representation takes. A structure, an `int`, an array, a union -- all are objects that have identities, can reside in memory, and in that case have addresses.  That "a collection of data" has internal structure does not mean that it fails to be "data" itself.

However, C does specify some rules for the representations of structures.  Specifically, the representation of a structure contains a representation of each member, in the order in which the members are declared, possibly with unnamed padding between members and / or after the last member.  No padding is allowed before the first member, and the language spec explicitly says that the address of a structure, converted to the correct type, points to that structure's first member.

Maybe this crude illustration will help:

```
+---+--------------------+-+   :
|   |  x.a               | |   :
| x |                    | |   a
|   |                    | |   d
|   +--------------------+ |   d
|     [... optional ...]   |   r
|   +--------------------+ |   e
|   | x.b                | |   s
|   |                    | |   s
|   |                    | |   :
|   +--------------------+ |   :
|     [... optional ...]   |   V
+---+----------------------+
```

Comment: I think this is what the thrust of the question was looking for -- ASCII art -- well done.

Answer (score 0):

When you've spent enough time meditating on ideas like this, you'll eventually come to see that, in the executable, there are no `int`s, `char`s, arrays or `struct`s. Machine code does not have those concepts.

The compiler *interprets* the source code, emitting machine instructions to manipulate the values of bytes of memory.

If the source code doesn't mention `unsigned`, arithmetic operations will be cognisant of negative values.

If the source code mentions an array, multiple adjacent bytes will be reserved and addressed according to whether the array an array of `char` or `int` or `double`, etc.

If the source code mentions a `struct`, again, multiple adjacent bytes will be reserved. The compiler calculates the correct offset (from the beginning) for the location of each member of the struct, emitting machine code with those offsets.

There are no `structs` in machine code; only instructions that deal with segments of memory as if they were the member variables.

`Array`s and `struct`s are abstractions used in writing source code.

This also helps in understanding why `sizeof` is an **operator**, not a function... The compiler *knows* the size of an array or a struct (in bytes)  and the built-in datatypes, too. The `sizeof` operator signals the compiler to emit that number at that point when generating object code. By the time a program is executing, `sizeof` anything cannot be determined...

Comment: Although it doesn't specifically answer the OP's question, it's still very well explained. +1 from me.

Comment: The last point in this answer implies [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) is strictly a compile-time construct, which is incorrect when dealing with [variable-length arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) - where `sizeof` is a run-time construct.

Comment: @Oka Good point. My excuse for the omission is my old (but trusty) compiler predating VLAs... Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score -1):

In C, structure members are laid out in the order in which they appear in the `struct` declaration, at increasing offsets. The first member is at offset zero, which means that a pointer to the structure points to the first member.

Given:

```
struct ab {
 int a;
 int b;
} x;
```

This comparison yields true:

```
(int) &x == &x.a
```

whereas this one yields false:

```
(int) &x == &x.b
```

To compare the pointers, We must convert one pointer to the type of the other, or else convert both to `char *` or `void *`. A pointer to a `struct` type and a pointer to `int` are not compatible.

The member `a` is allocated at an offset of zero bytes into the structure such that the expression:

```
offsetof(struct ab, a)
```

yields zero. (`offsetof` is in `<stddef.h>`).